# Private Set Intersection Polynomial Computation

Tags: elgamal-encryption, private-set-intersection

I am trying to implement the protocol mentioned in Section 3.4 of “[Efficient Robust Private Set Intersection](http://www.ece.umd.edu/~danadach/MyPapers/set-int.pdf)” in Java.

In the Second Step, the Client computes a polynomial of degree $n$ over the finite field.

For $C=\{1,2\}$, will the Polynomial be $x^2-3x+2$?

Can the polynomial have negative coefficients over the finite field? If yes, how do I encrypt the negative coefficients using Additive ElGamal?